# How to change directory and list output more times?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a folder which contains seven directories

```
meas_2015-06-29_19-03-00  meas_2015-06-29_19-18-28  meas_2015-06-29_19-22-58  meas_2015-06-29_19-26-58  meas_2015-06-29_19-30-58  meas_2015-06-29_19-47-58  meas_2015-06-29_20-39-58
```

Each of them has xml file,where all the measurement parameters have been written including this line

```
<num_samples>245760</num_samples>
```

I want all seven number of samples written on the screen.

How should I write shell script for this?Should I use alias's or ...?
I have tried like this

```
grep -Ri "num-samples" "*.xml" | wc -l
```

But got

```
grep: *.xml: No such file or directory
0
```

So I need to enter every subdirectory first.

Comment: What's the name of xml file in your seven directories?

Comment: @Cyrus XML is written authomatically so it changes for every directory.263_2015-06-29_19-03-00_2015-06-29_19-05-00_R000_2048H.xml for th first one,263_2015-06-29_19-18-28_2015-06-29_19-19-58_R000_131072H.xml for the second itd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep -Ri "num_samples" *` will provide an output similar to following:

```
meas_2015-06-29_19-03-00/a.xml:        <num_samples>245760</num_samples>
meas_2015-06-29_19-18-28/a.xml:        <num_samples>245760</num_samples>
meas_2015-06-29_19-22-58/a.xml:        <num_samples>245760</num_samples>
meas_2015-06-29_19-26-58/a.xml:        <num_samples>245760</num_samples>
meas_2015-06-29_19-30-58/a.xml:        <num_samples>245760</num_samples>
meas_2015-06-29_19-47-58/a.xml:        <num_samples>245760</num_samples>
meas_2015-06-29_20-39-58/a.xml:        <num_samples>245760</num_samples>
```

**Also, note that in your grep command, you have used `-` (num-samples) instead of `_` (num_samples)**

`grep -Rih "num_samples" *` will exclude file names from the output.
`grep -Ri "num_samples" * | sed 's/<\/.*//g; s/:\s\+.*>/ /g'` will provide following:

```
meas_2015-06-29_19-03-00/a.xml 245760
meas_2015-06-29_19-18-28/a.xml 245760
meas_2015-06-29_19-22-58/a.xml 245760
meas_2015-06-29_19-26-58/a.xml 245760
meas_2015-06-29_19-30-58/a.xml 245760
meas_2015-06-29_19-47-58/a.xml 245760
meas_2015-06-29_20-39-58/a.xml 245760
```

`grep -Rih "num_samples" * | grep -o '[0-9]\+'` will provide the value of each `<num_samples>` in each file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this with GNU grep:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\+' meas_*/*.xml
```

Comment: There might be more lines, without <num_samples>. First grep the `"<num_samples>"` and cut off the tags with your `grep -o` (or use `tr`).